# C# get iPad/iPhone MAC/Wifi address

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, wifi, mac-address

I am trying to find a solution to get the client's iPad unique MAC/Wifi address. I found some solutions here but it gets the MAC address of the server, but I want the client's address.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve the clients MAC address, the MAC address is determined by the clients hardware and due to many restrictions your web application tipically can´t get it.
I tried various workarrounds using javascript a long time ago without any success.

Here is a more detailed discussion about the same topic:
[how to get mac address of client that browse web site by asp.net mvc c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756179/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-that-browse-web-site-by-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp)