# How to get incoming request ip address using .net Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, ip-address

I deployed my .NET CORE solution in AZURE environment (PAAS).I used following code snippet there to get client's ip address

```
 dtoItem.LogIP = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
```

I used standard .net core libraries and did necessary changes into Startup.cs as well

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
    RequireHeaderSymmetry = false,
});
```

I believe I have implemented everything in correct manner. But still I haven't got accurate client IP address. I am always getting client's public IP instead of his private IP. Since this can be repeated (Same office 2 users have same public IP) I need client's private IP instead of his public IP.

Is it possible to get private IP address in PAAS solution. If it is not possible, is there a way to track client's PC information. (Such as IP Address, MAC address).

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756278/1033684

Comment: can you explain what you mean by client's public\private IP? If client is 'hidden' behind a NAT\router, then the requests will be issued by that router, and there's not much you can do on the server to discover the internal 'hidden' ip. One thing you could do is have your client side extract that information from the client device and send it along the request, but then you have to control the client, so won't work with dumb HTTP requests.

Comment: This question is more of a generic .net core question rather than a question regarding hosting in Azure App Service. Not sure what you are trying to solve here, but if you want to get the ip address of a computer behind NAT you won't be able to do this with server side code, but rather you'll need some java-script that runs on the client to get this data and then either attach it to outgoing requests or post it back to your site.

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions. @itaysk - please refer this article.it explains differences between Public and Private IP's. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm). I think extracting IP address via javascript would be good solution. Do you have solid JS to extract client IP address Byron Tardif

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to get private IP address in PAAS solution?

> No it is not possible as shared in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756179/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-that-browse-web-site-by-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp) and this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36583/can-a-website-still-detect-my-real-mac-address-even-if-i-use-different-virtual-m) address this about MACAddress

On the client side javascript, there is no API exposed to get the IPAddress(obviously due to security consideration) .Then you can get the IPAddress on the server side but typically if you are accessing internet from your company,it would go through the corporate proxy and the Ipaddress seen by the server will never be the actual client IP but the proxy server's address. So this is limited on the server side as server only sees the proxy (public IP address).

If it is not possible, is there a way to track client's PC information. (Such as IP Address, MAC address) ?

What you can reliably track is the user agent. Breaking the user agent down, we get the [some](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx#UnderstandUA)  information about browser ,OS versions. But user agent can easily be spoofed with some browser extension .

> If you are looking for browser finger printing or tracking ,have a
>   look at [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) which shows some  more information like
>   fonts > installed, screen resolution,plugins installed etc to track
>   any client. [fingerprintjs2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) javascript library helps to [track
>   using 26 parameters](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2#list-of-fingerprinting-sources) as of today

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward answer to this. The thread shared by Rob has some great insights. However, one needs to understand that a lot can happen to the request before it reaches the server. The intermediary networking devices can manipulate the TCP headers so it may not reflect the correct IP Address that you need.

From a solution perspective, this might be perfectly possible, if you develop your own client and log this information somewhere so that you can track it. Otherwise there is no reliable way to get this information.