# How to get client machine mac address from Javascript or jquery or MVC4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC4 application where I need to get client side MAC Address , Please let me know . If any solution is there ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get mac address of client that browse web site by asp.net mvc c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756179/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-that-browse-web-site-by-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp)

Comment: Using client js not possible, !

Comment: Anyway the short answer is you can't do it from Javascript for security reasons. The browser has very little access to the user's machine, to stop malicious websites from damaging it or stealing data. It's also pretty much impossible to do it from the server side as well - see the link given by Kiran above. Why do you think you need the MAC address anyway? I'm guessing this is some misguided attempt at licensing or user tracking. If you explain your actual goal perhaps there's a better way to achieve it, or perhaps it's not achievable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAC addresses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript)

Comment: ADyson ,Thanks for your reply .. Client requirement  is that Web Application should open from some predefined systems only . Please tell me how to achieve that requirement?