# How to find MAC address of Client PC using c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mac-address

This is my code for find MAC address, but it show same result when I run this in any device?

```
 public string GetMACAddress1()
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkInterface[] anics=NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in anics)
            {
                if (amacaddress == String.Empty)
                {
                    IPInterfaceProperties properties =adapter.GetIPProperties();
                    amacaddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();                       
                }
            }
            return "MAC Address is :- " + amacaddress;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

How can I got this.?

Comment: Your method is only going to ever return the value of the first MAC address found. Why would this change?

Comment: That's right, as soon as you get the first value, `amacaddress` won't be `Empty` anymore, so you won't enter the `if` anymore. Therefore, the rest of your `foreach` loop is useless

Comment: How to resolve it?

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: if someone view my site second time with same device, i want to show items similar to his previous selections.

Comment: Your code gets the MAC addresses of network adapters of the machine running the code, in this case, your server. The MAC address will therefore always be the same. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756179/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-that-browse-web-site-by-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp

Comment: Why not using cookies for your Problem?