# How to get client MAC address in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, mac-address

I've Login Page I want to get user client Mac Address but I write this code when I was published to server getting to server MACID. How can I get for User client Address

```
string NetworkMacID = "";
IPGlobalProperties computerProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
if (nics == null || nics.Length < 1)
  NetworkMacID = "";
else
  NetworkMacID = nics[0].GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();

return NetworkMacID;
```

Comment: Well, for one thing you'll only get a MAC address when the client is on the same physical network (or more accurately, the same broadcast domain) as the server.

Comment: You can't do this because Asp.Net runs on the server side, not client side. If you want to get client MAC you have to use Javascript which runs on the client machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get mac address of client that browse web site by asp.net mvc c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756179/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-that-browse-web-site-by-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp)