# (C# ASP.Net MVC) How do I prevent people from join in the survey more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, survey

I am designing an online Survey system for my website. 
(I am using C#,Asp.Net, Mvc, jquery)

**Survey is public for everyone and all users are annonymous. So they havent any username and password.**

When any user connects my page, I am adding an javascript cookie to user's Web Browser and also I am saving user's IP address to my SQL table.

If same user wants to connect to my page again, then I am checkin Browser's cookie and Users Ip Addres in My Sql Tables.  If I find any matched info in this object then I am giving some message to user like this :"You have already completed this survey. Please wait for the results to be announced "

**My problem is that:**
If user clear the cookies in the Browser and change IP address, then how can i notice this user already joined the survey before?  Is there any else solution?

Comment: Maybe you can get client machinenname or mac address

Comment: @erdiyılmaz No, both of those are terrible solutions. Most of the time you [can't get the proper MAC address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756179/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-that-browse-web-site-by-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp) and someone can easily change their machine name (even if you're able to attain it).

Comment: What you're asking for is not really possible. If you just want to host an anonymous survey, then you'll just have to live with it. If you have actual users that have accounts, you can easily limit it. Or if you're sending the survey announcement to people via email or some other form of communication, you can include a unique code in the URL for each person that gives them access to the survey. If the code has already been used, then they won't be able to fill the survey out again.

Comment: You store the IP in you database, aren't you? You need to decide this on the server side then, not in JS. Query the DB, match the IP and display the error you described. Strawpoll does the same thing. https://www.strawpoll.me/

Comment: Note that relying on IP address is also very problematic: people can just use a VPN, or go to their local coffee shop, or do the survey from their phone. Plus there are places (offices and college campuses for example) where large numbers of people will share the same IP.

Comment: You can't street too much about IP if the survey is anonymous. The only way to prevent real duplicates is to use registration and login. (Though, even than, you would need captchas, email confirmation..etc and some people could still cheat).

Comment: Yesss. I am saving user's Ip Adress in my database.  Namely I am trying to check  both cookie info with javascript and  also database records with c#.  But they are still not enaught..